# Incorrect cross compiling to ARMv6 in Go project

Tags: linux, go, arm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross compile a Go program for the armv6l architecture, specifically to get it running on a Raspberry Pi Zero W.

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
model name  : ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)
BogoMIPS    : 697.95
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp java tls
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xb76
CPU revision    : 7

Hardware    : BCM2835
Revision    : 9000c1
Serial      : 0000000059e0c5a9
Model       : Raspberry Pi Zero W Rev 1.1
```

I was doing what I thought was right by running the [command](https://github.com/vernak2539/dht_sensor_exporter/blob/master/Makefile#L14):

```
env CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux GOARM=6 GOARCH=arm go build -o build/dht_sensor_exporter-$(VERSION)-linux-armv6 ./cmd/main.go
```

At first glance, after running `file dht_sensor_exporter-$(VERSION)-linux-armv6` it looks good, as it outputs:

```
dht_sensor_exporter-$(VERSION)-linux-armv6: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, BuildID[sha1]=d84b6c4b0dc4b77b9c65db7bc30823e5dbe1078c, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, with debug_info, not stripped
```

When I try to run it on the Pi Zero W, it then outputs `Illegal instruction`. After a bit of digging, it seems that the cross compile didn't actually generate the file for the right architecture.

I found this using the following command:

```
$ readelf -A dht_sensor_exporter
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "7-A"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Application
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv3-D16
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_rounding: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_ABI_VFP_args: VFP registers
  Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6
```

Looking at the `Tag_CPU_arch` it seems that it's been compiled for ARMv7 actually.

Any help would be much appreciated. The repo in question is [here](https://github.com/vernak2539/dht_sensor_exporter) and is built using github actions ([workflow](https://github.com/vernak2539/dht_sensor_exporter/blob/master/.github/workflows/build_and_publish.yml), [makfile](https://github.com/vernak2539/dht_sensor_exporter/blob/master/Makefile#L6)) on the latest ubuntu version.

I'm still new at this and had to do some "interesting," potentially incorrect things with the C/C++ compiler (`arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc`)